# Hyper-v passthrough of usb nfc reader

Tags: hyper-v, usb, windows-server-2022

Is there any way to passthrough a NFC reader ([ACS 122U](https://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/3/acr122u-usb-nfc-reader/)) to an Hyper-V guest?

I have a windows server 2022 host, drivers installed correctly.
I already configured the required GPOs from this article [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-do-i-enable-a-usb-device-in-remote-desktop/113af42e-5b99-4f6b-bc6f-f8bc1007e34f) but it still isn't recognised.
Works fine in an ESXi host same windows server guest.

Comment: You can try experimenting with Get-PnPDevice.  See: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/passing-through-devices-to-hyper-v-vms-by-using-discrete-device-assignment/

Comment: @GregAskew looks promising, thank you